# 'Twython' object has no attribute... Error running examples

Tags: python, twitter, raspberry-pi, twython

I am trying to run the Twython examples in the `core_examples` folder and I get the same error on all the files.

If I run the file: `weekly_trends.py`  I get the error:

```
'Twython' object has no attribute 'weekly_trends.py'.
```

If I run the file: `getCurrentTrends.py`  I get the error:

```
'Twython' object has no attribute 'getCurrentTrends'.
```

I have tried running the code on my Raspberry Pi and OSX and I get the same error.  I assume I am missing a key part of the installation process or the authentication.  I have a Twitter App setup and I have the keys and tokens.  Do I need to enter these anywhere to get it to work? I got Tweepy working but Twython looks like it may have the ability to add images to tweets.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, we don't have `core_examples` in the repo anymore, so I'm not sure what version of Twython you're running. For reference, those keys you have need to be used in the Twython instantiation, ala:

```
from twython import Twython
t = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
auth_tokens = t.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)
print auth_tokens
# method calls, etc...
```

Apologies on seeing this so late, SO slips away from me when work takes over my life. Hope you're on your way!